# Lighten individual background-color with hover by scss - how?

Tags: css, sass

I have some blocks with different background-colors (which are set in variables) and if a user hovers one of them, the color shall light/fade a bit.

Therefore I use this one:

```
.block1:hover,.block2:hover{
    background-color:lighten($color1,40%);
}
```

But this just fades one static color - $color1 - to 40%. How would I do that, if .block1 had $color1 and .block2 had $color2 as background colors set? So the result should be

```
 .block1:hover{
        background-color:lighten($color1,40%);
    }
.block2:hover{
        background-color:lighten($color2,40%);
    }
```

What do I need to use therefore?

Comment: I don't get it. It seems like the 2nd piece of CSS answers your question?

Comment: Probably want to use a mixin here.

Comment: @Rvervuurt: Nope, it doesn't. It just displays the result AFTER what scss shall do. But I asked for the way to get there, what Joshs' answer fully solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a mixin, like so:

```
.block1 {
  .backgroundsetup($color1);
}
.block2 {
  .backgroundsetup($color2);
}

.backgroundsetup($color, $amt: 40%) {
  background-color: $color;

  &:hover {
    background-color: lighten($color, $amt);
  }
}
```

Comment: This isn't valid SASS or LESS

Answer (score 0):

There's no special way to write the CSS you have in your example in SCSS, that would be the way you do it. But if you want to optimize and write less code, then you could take advantage of SASS' hashmaps and the foreach loop to do this for you.

**SASS**

```
$color1: #4e9bac;
$color2: #248cff;
$color3: #3b5998;

$blocks: (
    block1: $color1,
    block2: $color2,
    block3: $color3,
);

@each $block, $color in $blocks {
  .#{$block} {
    background-color: $color;

      &:hover {
        background-color: lighten($color, 40%);
      }
  }
}
```

**CSS Output**

```
.block1 {
  background-color: #4e9bac;
}
.block1:hover {
  background-color: #d8eaee;
}

.block2 {
  background-color: #248cff;
}
.block2:hover {
  background-color: #f0f7ff;
}

.block3 {
  background-color: #3b5998;
}
.block3:hover {
  background-color: #bbc8e4;
}
```